# C# function overriding

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

I am learning C# Inheritance. I have seen Programmers using `base.method()` statement when overriding a function. For example:-

```
protected override void OnClear()
            {
                _currentPos = 0;
                _albumFilename = null;
                this.Dispose();                                 
                base.OnClear();     // Why this Statement is used?
            }
```

Can any one please explain the use of `base.OnClear()` statement here? I shall be glad and thankful to you ! Please share you knowledge :-)

Comment: This calls the base version of the method, i.e. the version of `OnClear` that you are overriding. Calling it after `Dispose`, however, looks wrong to me...

Comment: `base.OnClear()` is a call of inherited (parent, base etc.) `OnClear()` method

Comment: Do you mean that base.OnClear() will call the original method defined in the base class? Or will it call the current overrided function here?

Comment: This is abstract in collectionbase(),  the OnClear()  is called by CollectionBase just before Clear() is called. If you are not implementing your custom requirement after then no need to call it specifically. You can refer msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.onclear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For some silly reason, it looks like we hate new people here who want to learn and dare to ask! We slap them on the wrist by DAMNED DOWNVOTING! At minimum who downvotes should have the guts to say: I downvoted because, not just anonymously...

Comment: Thanks For Supporting @iplavlu Sir :-) 
 And Thanks Everyone for your response and precious time :-) 
 I got my answer and learnt something new !

Comment: @HNLearner - You may like to accept the answer if any of them helped. See how to accept an answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: Sure Sir ! :)

Answer (score 3):

To call OnClear() method of the parent class, this code base.OnClear() method has been used.

Since you're overriding the method from the parent class, so if you want to call the parent class' method, you should use `base` keyword to access parent class members.

From [MSDN's documentation on `base`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

> The base keyword is used to access members of the base class from
>   within a derived class:
>
> 1. Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method.
>      ...

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple it is because the overridden method has some functionality you need, it knows how to clear data in the original class and has access to its private parts. You as the inheritor don't. So you need to call the original implementation to clear data in the base class and your overridden part of code handles your data.

Comment: It is usually dependent on the implementation. Here I would say last as your class might depend on some parts of the base class that is set to some latest state.